# jquery reduce flicker effect for page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a side bar which i am replacing with new_sidebar url , but while doing so i first see the old br loading and then the new contents .Its kind of a flicker effect.Is there a way than i can reduce the flickering effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
   $(".bar").empty();
   $(".bar").load("{% url 'get_bar' %}");
});
```

Comment: Hide it with CSS by default, then show it when it's done loading the new sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

CSS :

```
<style>
    .sidebar
    {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
   $(".bar").empty();
   $(".bar").load("{% url 'get_bar' %}");
   $(".bar").show();
});
```

Comment: no, you need to put it in <style> tag inside <head> tag

Comment: k will try and let you know